# How can I modify a particular field in a list of data frames?

Tags: r

Suppose I write the following R code:

```
first.value <- sample(100, 100, replace=TRUE)
second.value <- sample(10, 100, replace=TRUE)

X <- data.frame(first.value, second.value)
split.X <- split(X, second.value)
```

This code creates a data frame with two fields, and splits into bins according to the second.  Now suppose I wanted to normalize each bin; i.e., subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation.  I could accomplish this by

```
normalized.first.value <- sapply(split.X, function(X) {(X$first.value - mean(X$first.value)) / sd(X$first.value)})
```

But this creates a new list with the normalized versions of each bin.  What I really want to do is replace the copy of the data in `split.X` with its normalized version.

To illustrate, here's some sample output:

```
> first.value <- sample(100, 100, replace=TRUE)
> second.value <- sample(10, 100, replace=TRUE)
> X <- data.frame(first.value, second.value)
> split.X <- split(X, second.value)
> normalized.first.value <- sapply(split.X, function(X) {(X$first.value - mean(X$first.value)) / sd(X$first.value)})
> split.X[[1]]
   first.value second.value
4           34            1
8           40            1
24          21            1
31          34            1
37          23            1
40          22            1
> normalized.first.value[[1]]
[1]  0.625  1.375 -1.000  0.625 -0.750 -0.875
```

What I really want to do is to put the values of `normalized.first.value[[1]]` into `split.X[[1]]$first.value`, and the same for the other indices.

This could be achieved with a `for` loop as follows:

```
for (i in 1:length(split.X)) {
  split.X[[i]]$first.value <- (split.X[[i]]$first.value - mean(split.X[[i]]$first.value) / sd(split.X[[i]]$first.value);
}
```

But `for` loops are BAD in R, and I'd like to use `sapply`,`lapply`, etc. if I can.  Unfortunately, when dealing with a list of dataframes, `sapply` and `lapply` don't seem to iterate in the way I want.

Comment: For loops aren't necessarily bad in R. Sometimes they can be easier to read than `*apply` and not necessarily slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Map` as both the lists have the same length.  It works by replacing the first column in 'split.X' by the corresponding the `list` element in 'normalized.first.value'

```
  Map(function(x,y) {x[['first.value']] <- y;x} ,split.X, normalized.first.value)
```

Or we can loop through the length of 'split.X', get the list elements of the 'split.X' and 'normalized.first.value' based on the index and then replace.

```
  lapply(seq_along(split.X), function(i) {
             x1 <- split.X[[i]]
             x1[,'first.value'] <- normalized.first.value[[i]]
             x1})
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is it possible to replace the `x[[1]]` in the first example with something that refers to the name of the field (`first.value`) in case another field gets added in before?

Comment: @Donkey_2009  I updated the post.  You can quote the 'first.value' and it should work inside `[[`

Comment: @Donkey_2009 Glad to help you.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more arcane way (though I still reckon the `for` loop is fine in this case)

```
new.split.X <- mapply(`[<-`, split.X, T, 'first.value', normalized.first.value,
                      SIMPLIFY=F)
```

How it works: applies `[<-` on each `split.X[[i]]`. The `T` is the `i` index to replace (i.e. all of them), `'first.value'` is the `j` index to replace (that column), `normalized.first.value` contains the replacements.

The loop may be easier to read in the end though, and probably not slower than tricksy `*apply` solutions.

```
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(loop={
    for (i in 1:length(split.X))
        split.X[[i]]$first.value <- normalized.first.value[[i]]
  },
  mapply={
    mapply(`[<-`, split.X, T, 'first.value', normalized.first.value,
                          SIMPLIFY=F)
  },
  Map={
    Map(function(x,y) {x[['first.value']] <- y;x} ,split.X, normalized.first.value)
  },
  lapply={
    lapply(seq_along(split.X), function(i) {
             x1 <- split.X[[i]]
             x1[,'first.value'] <- normalized.first.value[[i]]
             x1})
  })
    test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
4 lapply          100   0.034    4.857     0.035        0          0         0
1   loop          100   0.007    1.000     0.007        0          0         0
3    Map          100   0.012    1.714     0.013        0          0         0
2 mapply          100   0.030    4.286     0.032        0          0         0
```

So the explicit loop is the fastest, and easieset to read anyway.